# java - best way to determine -Xmx and -Xms required for any webapp & standalone app

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory

I'd like to know how to determine the heap size required for a standalone app as well as a webapp running on a tomcat server.

How to determine the same after deployment on the server.

Thanks.

Comment: -Xmx Increase, until no out of memory errors happen and the CPU usage is not dominated by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 5):

You can start with profiling the memory usage. The JDK (6 upwards) has its [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/) for example. A tool I personally prefer is the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), originally from SAP, now open. You can analyze heap dumps or hook it up to a java process of your choice.
To programmatically create heap dumps you can use [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java)

Answer (score 4):

Rule suggested by [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg000139b8b453-11951f1e7ff-8000_1001.html) for Sizing the Java heap , it is for IBM SDK but i dont think there would be much difference in these settings for other SDK's.

> Size your Java heap so that your application runs with a minimum heap
>   usage of 40%, and a maximum heap usage of 70%.

Answer (score 1):

we use the `-Xloggc:gc-log.txt`and `-XX:+PrintGCdetails` option on the VM and let it run for a while (days) with hig Xmx settings and then you can use [GCViewer](http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html) to render a diagram from the log and get an idea of when how much RAM was consumed, i.e. whether there were peaks, limits reached, loads of GCs slowing down the App, etc.