# Managing Java Memory with Xms and Xmx

Tags: java, memory, jconsole

I had a java application that runs as a daemon process.  Initially, I discovered that after about a week, the applicaiton would throw an out of memory error.  I researching, I discovered that I could manage the memory and avoid the problem by setting the -Xms and -Xmx flags at startup to specify how much memory the application would have.  This ultimately resolved my memory problem.

However, later on, I discovered that the application was causing performance issues on some machines that only had 1GB of memory, 1GB of memory was how much I had allocated for -Xmx.  So the java application took all of available memory.

So using jconsole, I was about to determine that the application ran at about 150mb.  So using that information, I dropped the -Xmx value to 300mb.  Thinking that it would be plenty.  But then I discovered that the application was only using about 15mb.  Why?  Why does the application use 150mb when its allocated 1GB, but only 15mb when its allocated 300mb?

And how do I go about figuring out what I should be using?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742070/java-best-way-to-determine-xmx-and-xms-required-for-any-webapp-standalone